# Input values in a column according to the reference from another column of the same sheet

Tags: vba, excel

hi I have a problem in inputting values into a column with conditions and referring to the other 2 or more columns to determine the input of the other column using VBA. for example there are 3 columns called RAG cost (C), RAG Resources (R) and RAG Benefits (B). this 3 columns will determine the input value in a column called Overall RAG using VBA.
for example if column (C) or column (B) contains the value"R" , then the overall RAG Status will be input as "A" in the respective rows. I tried using the if else statement but it doesn't seems to work.
to make it clearer this is the example: if RAG Cost(C) OR RAG Resources(R) VALUES = "R" then Overall RAG status= "A".

Comment: The wording of your question is exceeding unclear. Please clarify what you are trying to do and show what have already attempted including any code.

Comment: Hi, in an excel file I have 4 columns header. 1st column is named as Overall status, 2nd column as Cost, 3rd column as benefits & 4th column  as resources. Each column will have values in it such as either R means Red, G means Green & A means Amber. Only the Overall Status column remained empty unless one of the 3 other columns contain the value R in any of its rows. thus,the overall status column will appear as value A. for eg: if in row 2 in column resources contains value R while both columns on benefit and cost contain value "G" the "overall status" column in row 2 will appear as value "A"

Comment: I have deleted the previous coding that I have done because it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need vba for this you can write a simple formula like

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("R",B2:D2,0)),"","A")
```

If You want code please try this

```
Sub rgb()
Dim lstrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim j As Long

lstrow = Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 2 To lstrow
    For j = 2 To LastCol
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value = "R" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = "A"
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Thank you for your help! it works!

Comment: If it helps you please vote or accept the answer